# Classic ASP website using windows authentication takes a while to load the first time after some time of inactivity

Tags: performance, authentication, iis, asp-classic, page-load-time

My company has a Classic ASP website, hosted in IIS 10 on Windows Server 2016, that I have been tasked with optimizing the load time for. I have done everything else to get the page running optimally, however after about 5 or 10 minutes of inactivity, the page load of any given page takes about 10-15 seconds to load (then it runs smoothly afterwards until the next 5 or 10 minutes of inactivity). I have already disabled the idle timeout and the played with the recycling properties, so I have already ruled that out. I have even played with the keep-alive timeout header value which has no affect on the behavior in question.

What I believe I have narrowed it down to is the authentication. The website uses Windows Authentication and expects a company domain account to enter the admin area of the site. And, if I access any part of the site that doesn't require authentication, this page load delay does not happen. I am thinking that maybe our company has a domain policy in place that automatically logs a user out of a session after some specific amount of time of inactivity. And so maybe the site is just re-authenticating after each automatic logout which causes the delay.  Any ideas?

Comment: It may not be about authentication method. Are you using SQL or Access database? Are you using joined tables?

Answer (score -1):

Try adding the following settings in the webconfig. It will set the session state expire after 30 minutes.

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
     <sessionState timeout="30"></sessionState>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Comment: I have already tried that (implicitly via IIS) but it didn't make any difference.

Comment: Have you made sure that you rs.close , conn.close, set rs = nothing, set conn = nothing immediately after they are done being used?  This makes a huge difference on performance.  Although your post seems to lean on the domain controller being the issue,  I have a system I built that uses this type of authentication and we have no delay even with an older controller.  Do you still have any Win 7 systems on the network or something like that?

Comment: Also as a suggestion, build an include file with a timer in it for the start and stop at the end, and have it log the results to a table so you can get some actual numbers to work with to not only know what your current actual speed is, but also have some history to compare against changes you make.

Comment: Try with other authentication method to see whether it works well. If it is all about domain policy, you may need to contact the administrator.